# Calling a JFrame in another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am using NetBeans. I have to make two JFrames in separate files such as test1.java and test2.java. test1 is a simple registration form and test2 is a webcam application that captures an image.

I want to show the test2 JFrame in the Test1 JFrame. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is called a [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html), and is a separate component than a JFrame.

Look here for an explanation of internal frames

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

You should be able to change your `test2` frame into an internal frame to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was create a whole new class that makes it own GUI. I did not add a main method, I just called it something else. And when I wanted that GUI page to pop up, I just called it with your usual `Page page = new Page()` method. There was one other thing that I did. Instead of the typical `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` I used `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` so that the whole thing does not exit when you hit the red X, it just gets rid of the window, and lets the other one stay open